Google Sheets: SUMPRODUCT Formula for Summing Income and Expenses by Month Across Multiple Sheets
I am a beginner in Google Sheets and I'm working on a workbook with three sheets: Income, Expenditure, and Summary. My goal is to create a summary sheet that automatically calculates the total income and expenses for each month and displays the results in the corresponding rows.
Workbook Structure:
Income Sheet: Contains columns for Date, Description, and Amount.
Expenditure Sheet: Contains columns for Date, Description, and Amount.
Summary Sheet: Contains columns for Month, Total Income, Total Expenses, and Net Profit/Loss.
What I Want to Achieve:
In the Summary sheet, I want the Total Income column to automatically sum the amounts from the Income sheet based on the month and year.
Similarly, I want the Total Expenses column to sum the amounts from the Expenditure sheet based on the month and year.
The Net Profit/Loss should then be calculated as the difference between Total Income and Total Expenses for each month.
Formula Attempt:
I attempted to use the SUMPRODUCT function to achieve this for the Total Income column. Here is the formula I tried:
=SUMPRODUCT((TEXT(Income!A:A,"mmmm")="January")*(Income!C:C))

However, I am receiving an error and I'm unsure how to resolve it.
Issues:
Error Message: The formula throws an error and doesn’t return the expected results.
Date Matching: I’m not sure if the date matching is being done correctly using the TEXT function within SUMPRODUCT.
Additional Information:
The Date column in both Income and Expenditure sheets is in mm/dd/yyyy format.
I want to ensure the formula dynamically updates for all months, not just January.
Here is a link to a dummy template of my workbook for reference
What I Need:
Assistance in correcting the formula or a better approach to achieve the desired result.
Any suggestions on how to efficiently sum the income and expenses by month, ensuring the summary sheet updates automatically as data is added to the income and expenditure sheets.
Thank you in advance for your help!

Try to change your formulas to:
=SUMPRODUCT(TEXT(Income!A:A,"mmmm")=A2,Income!D:D)
=SUMPRODUCT(TEXT(Expenditure!A:A,"mmmm")=A2,Expenditure!D:D)


SUM THE INCOME AND EXPENSES BY MONTH
You can use this script for better approach on you worksheet. Ensure dates in the Income and Expenditure sheets are in the "MM/DD/YYYY" format by selecting the date column and using Format > Number > Date.
Also I Adjust the formula for better understanding.
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A2:A="", "", IFERROR(SUMIF(TEXT(Income!A:A, "MMMM YYYY"), A2:A, Income!D:D), 0)))

This formula converts the dates to "MMMM YYYY" format, sums amounts in Income and Expenditure sheets cell D` for each month and handles errors by returning in 0 if no data matches.
For the Net Profit/Loss Subtracting expenses from income:
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A2:A="", "", B2:B - C2:C))

Notes: Make sure that the format date in Summary Sheet will be "MMMM YYYY" format like in the Output.
Sample Output
Input formula in Cell B2 to get Income Sheet Cell D value.

Input formula in Cell C2 to get Expenditure Sheet Cell D value.

Subtraction for the Total Income and Total Expenses.

For the TOTALS I used the formula.
Cell B14 - =SUM(B2:B13)
Cell C14 - =SUM(C2:C13)
Cell D14 - =B14-C14
Reference :

ArrayFormula

SUMIF

IF Function

IFERROR



Thank you, will check it out and revert as soon as possible.

Please feel free to ask anything with respect to the answer posted above.
If this answers your question, please click the accept button on the left (check icon) and up-voting the answer. By doing so, other people in the community, who may have the same concern as you, will know that theirs can be resolved.
